# Pass array into Vue JS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to pass a `php object` into a `Vue JS component` and use its keys in order to access its values within the component.

The syntax that I am using to parse the `php object` within the `vue component` must be incorrect because at the moment the object values within the `vue html` are showing up as `undefined undefined`.

I wondered if anyone had any useful suggestions?

***PHP blade file***

```
    @foreach($clients as $client)
    
        <client client='{!! json_encode($client) !!}' home-route="{{ route('clients.show', $client->id) }}"></client>
    @endforeach
```

***vue component***

```
    <template>
        <li :data-clientID="client.id"><a :href="this.homeRoute">{{ client.first_name + ' ' + client.last_name }}</a>
            <span class="delete_x" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_modal" :data-model="client.id">x</span>        
        </li>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        export default {
            name: 'client',
            props: {
                client: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                homeRoute: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

***Output***

[image]

Comment: Please show us the HTML generated.

Comment: You don't need `this.` in `:href="this.homeRoute"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `client` prop as `String` instead of object. Try:

```
export default {
    name: 'client',
    props: {
        client: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        homeRoute: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
```

and bind the `client` prop using `v-bind` so it's not interpreted as a string

```html
<client
  :client='{!! json_encode($client) !!}' 
  home-route="{{ route('clients.show', $client->id) }}"
></client>
```

Comment: Yup. @fromvega, that's because I am using json_encode to encode it as a json string in my blade template. It isn't an object.

Comment: All this answer needs is to change the prop binding to `:client` (or `v-bind:client`) so the JSON encoded string is interpreted as an object

Comment: @RobertYoung it's a string in PHP but in JavaScript it should be interpreted as an object.

Comment: @fromvega thankyou. I have just tried this and it works. Thanks for your help.